# What's the best Polaroid camera and model right now?

Tags: printer, polaroid

Of course, it should be able to print pictures without an external printer.

Comment: I'd suggest you find the film first, then a camera to use it. I know it has got nothing to do with your question, just felt like sharing.

Comment: I thought that The Impossible Project already sells its own films?

Comment: The Impossible Project's current films are _very_ finicky. They haven't gotten it all worked out yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one film-based [Polaroid brand instant camera](http://store.polaroid.com/category/0/354633/Classic_Instant) still sold by Polaroid.  They also sell [film](http://store.polaroid.com/products/0/354635/Instant_Film) for it.

Comes in three fun colours.

They also have [instant digital cameras](http://store.polaroid.com/category/0/266907/Polaroid_PoGo%26%238482%3B) now with built in "printer".  You don't need ink but you still need sheets of [photo paper](http://store.polaroid.com/products/0/307287/ZINK_Photo_Paper) for it.  Same thing but slower and more expensive (why would you bother?).

Comment: A printer built into a digital camera is an interesting idea. I can imagine scenarios where the ability to quickly produce prints at a remote location would be a big advantage.